# Rails loads css files from public/assets instead of app/assets in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I'm running in development mode.  I'm editing .css files but not seeing changes.  If I go to public/assets/ and rename application.css, I see changes (it can't find any styles).  Why would it be using that file?  Isn't that for production mode?  I don't want to pre-compile all the time in dev mode. thanks.   Environment files added below.

development.rb :

```
   Tcms::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

production.rb :

```
Tcms::Application.configure do
  # Uncomment and set this to match your production URL. Used for emailing links to the CMS. (default: localhost:3000)
  # config.cms.site_domain = "www.example.com"

  # Configure your mail server's address below
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => 'mail.yourmailserver.com', :domain => config.cms.site_domain}

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
   config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify


  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

Comment: Cam you add your config/environment/development.rb here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As default, Rails will serve assets within /public and not compiling live, if these assets exists.

To get rid of it, either delete the assets within the public dir,
or add the following line into you config/environments/development.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

> config.serve_static_assets configures Rails itself to serve static
>   assets. Defaults to true

More to read: [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

Answer (score 1):

What version of rails are you running? Is this an app that upgraded from 2.x or 3.0.x to 3.1 or 3.2? This almost sounds like this app was pre-asset pipline. Here is a good tutorial on upgrading from pre-asset pipline to asset-pipline...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1

...also here is a good basic tutorial for asset pipeline...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline