# Can't write new javascript on localhost without precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've made a Rails application and deployed to Heroku after compiling the assets. However, now that I've compiled the assets once, if I want to make changes to the javascript on localhost, I have to recompile the assets each time, otherwise the new javascript isn't registering properly and I can't see the changes on localhost, and this is making development very slow, as I have to wait for it to compile for each change.

Is there a setting I can add to avoid this problem?

These are the settings in my environments/development.rb file.

```
 config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin


  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
```

Comment: Make sure that public/assets is empty, and that you don't have the files cached in your browser.

Comment: @JimDeville so I have to delete the public assets folder after each compile if I want to continue developing on local host?

Comment: I forgot about `rake assets:clean`, which will clean them up for you. You should not have to do it after each compile, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611155/rails-loads-css-files-from-public-assets-instead-of-app-assets-in-development-mo?rq=1 for some ideas (sorry, i haven't done enough with assets to know the right fix here)